# Craft - Order by title that is a number

Tags: php, sorting, twig

In craft, I'm trying to order entries by the title, each title is a number, but the sort function handles it like a word. Because of that "100" shows up before "2", "31" before "4", and so on.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('mySection').order('title').find() %}
    <h2>§{{entry.title}}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Let's see your sorting code...!?

Comment: Sure, its just the basic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert with craft but as far as I know it internally uses [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/). So you could use the filter `|sort` but what you actually want is the use of the PHP function `natsort` or `natcasesort`.

It seems that it is not very straightforward to use this function, actually you need to add an extension to twig like [shown here (slide 51)](http://www.slideshare.net/javier.eguiluz/twig-tips-and-tricks):

```
class NatSortExtension extends Twig_Extension_Core {
    public function getFilters() {
        return array_merge(parent::getFilters(), array(
            "natsort" => new Twig_Filter_Method($this, "sortFilter")
        ));
    }
    public function sortFilter($array) {
        natcasesort($array);
        return $array;
    }
}
```

Now is the point where I don't know how craft works. In twig you add an extension like this:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment();
$twig->addExtension( new NatSortExtension());
```

Then you would be able to do this:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('mySection').order('title').find|natsort %}
    <h2>§{{entry.title}}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Sorry that I can't help further.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Craft plugin called [SuperSort](http://michaelrog.com/craft/lagniappe/supersort) that you can use with `natsort`.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('mySection').order('title').find()|supersort('natsort') %}
    <h2>§{{entry.title}}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```